# Display external cover Notion API with Next.js

Tags: next.js, notion-api

I'm creating my portfolio using Notion API, Next.js and Tailwind thanks to this wonderful work : https://github.com/samuelkraft/notion-blog-nextjs

However, as you may know, images hosted on Notion has an expiration time.
I tried to use
`<img src={blog.cover.file.url}/>` but if I upload a cover on my Notion page from an external link, all my code breaks.
I had a look on this documentation : https://developers.notion.com/changelog/page-icons-cover-images-new-block-types-and-improved-page-file-properties
but I don't know how to mention it's an external link.

Do you have any idea how I can solve this issue?

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `src={cover.external.url}` as mention in docs https://developers.notion.com/changelog/page-icons-cover-images-new-block-types-and-improved-page-file-properties.

```
{
    "object": "database",
    "id": "96433ad8-3fbe-460f-a007-72311c4aa804",
    "cover": {
        "type": "external",
        "external": {
            "url": "https://website.domain/images/image.png"
        }
    },
    "icon": {
        "type": "emoji",
        "emoji": ""
    },
    // ... remaining properties
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm a newbie in Javascript and it's been a nightmare finding this solution. Many thanks!